# Opencart add size option to search results

Tags: php, opencart

I was wondering if someone could explain how to add options to my search results (category, manufacture) etc. I just need them in a select tag (no actions required). I tried similar code to the product options but that didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution: http://www.opencartaz.com/opencart/attribute-options-on-category-page.html

```
<?php foreach ($products[$j]['options'] as $option) { ?>
    <select name="option[<?php echo $option['option_id']; ?>]">
        <?php foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $option_value['option_value_id']; ?>"><?php echo $option_value['name']; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
<?php } ?>
```